# How to add UIView on a UICollectionView cell programmatically in swift

Tags: ios

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
    var template: UIView
    template = UIView.init(frame: CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50))
    template.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.cell.addSubview(template)

    return cell
}
```

I tried dragging uiview into the collectionview cell on the storyboard and addSubview to the outlet but it also wont work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "self" in `self.cell` implies that it references a class/global variable, not the cell you create at the top of the method. Try changing `self.cell.addSubview(template)` to `cell.addSubview(template)`.

Also

```
var template: UIView
template = UIView.init(frame: CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50))
```

can be simplified to:

```
let template = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50))
```

Comment: How can we add that uiview on indexpath.row?